# How to suspress the position: relative when using translate

Tags: css, css-position, transform

it seems that using `transform: translateY(1px);` also causes the element to gain an extra `position: relative;`-behaviour.

Is there a way to suspress this?

Here is a example [on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqPaK).

I would like to position the whitebox absolutely to the green one, not the parent (red) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to displace/negate the parent's positioning by wrapping an element around `#three` (in this case, I added the `.displacement` element).

Absolutely position this wrapper element, and position it to cover the parent (using `top: 0`/`right: 0`/`bottom: 0`/`left: 0`). Then displace the element by giving it negative translation values, relative to the parent's.

```
<div class="displacement">
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

```
.displacement {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px) translateX(-25px);
  transform: translateY(-25px) translateX(-25px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 200%; height: 200%;
}
```

In doing so, the element `#three` is positioned absolutely *relative* to `#one`, and the parent `#two`'s translated positioning is effectively displaced.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEveZq)

```
.displacement {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px) translateX(-25px);
  transform: translateY(-25px) translateX(-25px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 200%; height: 200%;
}
#three {
  background-color: white;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This indeed, resolves the examples issue. But it won't work if you do not know all dimensions.. Lets say #three should be ´left: 0´ and ´right: 0´. This does not help then, does it?

Comment: @Gundon I figured out a work-around actually... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyxRza

Comment: Great idea! Mind sharing that as an answer? I'll tick it as answering then (:

Answer (score 0):

> `position:absolute` [(from moz)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

so in your case the closest ancestor will always be `#two` which doesn't inherit any position property , just default `position: static;`...

---

if you gave `#two` `position:relative// or absolute` and positioned it with `top:` and `left:`  maybe it's easier to place #three:
http://codepen.io/maio/pen/qEMJpY

Comment: Youre reading it wrong. The containing block is the fallback, not prioritized check. You can also see this when removing the transforms from #two. Then #three will be positioned to #one

Comment: I'm sure that two has position:static cause I checked dev-tools (also check adding a property like left:33px -> it doesn't react) ,since  #three is nested in # two that's where absolute positioning is being calculated from

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less-than-ideal workaround, but it works for your existing markup.

Change your `#two` CSS to a pseudo-element, adding these styles:

```
#two::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByOqrB)**

---

Short of changing your markup, your other solution is to use JavaScript to make `three` a child of element `one`:

```
document.querySelector('#one').appendChild(document.querySelector('#three'));
```

However, it will no longer inherit any styles from element `two`, as demonstrated in this 
**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEMJgM)**.

Here's an interesting read, which confirms "transforming an element force-adds position: relative.":  http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/

Not only that, but it also affects fixed-position elements, which doesn't make much sense.