# How to fix Framer Motion's `motion.div` `x, y` properties to no longer be relative to container element's positions?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have a custom cursor made with framer motion, that's placed like so in a next.js app:

```js
// app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import CustomCursor from "@/components/custom-cursor";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}<CustomCursor /></body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

My `CustomCursor` component is like so (slightly simplified):

```js
"use client"
const CustomCursor = ({ }: CustomCursorProps) => {
  const device = useDeviceDetection(); // for checking device type
  const mousePosition = useMousePosition(); // hook for getting mouse position
  const variants: Variants = {
    default: {
      x: mousePosition.x - 16,
      y: mousePosition.y - 16,
    },
    pointer: {
      x: mousePosition.x - 75,
      y: mousePosition.y - 75,
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
    }
  };
  const mouseVariant = useCursorStyleStore((state) => state.cursorStyle); // a zustand store for storing what type of cursor to use
  if (device !== "desktop") return <></>; // no cursor on mobiles or tablets
  return <div>
    <div className="bg-white h-2 w-2 rounded-[50%] fixed pointer-events-none mix-blend-difference z-50" style={{ top: mousePosition.y - 4, left: mousePosition.x - 4 }}></div>
    <motion.div className="bg-white h-8 w-8 rounded-[50%] fixed pointer-events-none mix-blend-difference z-40" variants={variants} animate={Object.keys(variants).includes(mouseVariant) ? mouseVariant : "default"} />
  </div>
}

export default CustomCursor;
```

In the component above, the `div` representing a cursor that follows the actual cursor precisely has no issues because it is using `top` and `bottom`, whereas since the `motion.div` uses `x`, and `y` which uses translate if im not wrong, and so causes it to position itself relative to the parent(?)'s position.

I've tried changing the parent div's position to relative and absolute, however, neither of them work. Changing `x` and `y` to `left` and `top` respectively makes the position of the `motion.div` to work however causes it to not animate as well. I've also tried editing the variants as well to see if anything would happen.

EDIT 3: I've tried changing my answer according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947938/how-to-suspress-the-position-relative-when-using-translate), and while it works in positioning the `motion.div` it causes an overflow on the document when the cursor is bought to the right and bottom edges.

```js
//....
return <div>
    <div className="bg-white h-2 w-2 rounded-[50%] fixed pointer-events-none mix-blend-difference z-50" style={{ top: mousePosition.y - 4, left: mousePosition.x - 4 }}></div>
    <motion.div className="absolute pointer-events-none mix-blend-difference z-40 top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 w-fit h-fit" variants={variants} animate={Object.keys(variants).includes(mouseVariant) ? mouseVariant : "default"} >
      <div className="bg-white h-8 w-8 absolute rounded-[50%]" />
    </motion.div>
  </div>
```